# Based on the included pictures, what kind of connector is this? Each pin is about 1.18mm in width and there's about a 3.96mm pin-to-pin width

Tags: power-supply, pcb, connector

I thought this might be a JST-VH connector based on dimensions, but it doesn't seem to look like one. I didn't have much luck with google images, so I thought to ask here. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Also, This connector is from a power supply.

Comment: Most power supply manuals explain which connectors they use. Which power supply make and model that is, and do you have a manual for it?

Comment: @Justme I should have looked that up! I pulled it out of a device so I thought it wasn't a common supply- but it is! I found the spec sheet for it. It is a Molex 5273-06A connector. http://c1170156.r56.cf3.rackcdn.com/UK_SKY_SNP-9031_DS.pdf

Comment: Molex KK series, although many others have compatible connectors. A very popular and copied style of connector - pretty much a generic. Pitch is 0.156" or 3.96mm.

Comment: awesome. Thanks @Kartman!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most probably a Molex, KK 396, 5273, 6 Way, 1 Row, Straight PCB Header.

Comment: You are right! I just found it after looking at a spec sheet for the power supply itself. Thanks! http://c1170156.r56.cf3.rackcdn.com/UK_SKY_SNP-9031_DS.pdf

Comment: Anytime, Allen!

Answer (score 0):

Molex 0009652088 with 8 PINs. your connector is 7 PINs.